# How to correctly fill the grid antd with data from the server

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I made such a grid using grid antd . code [here](https://codepen.io/sharoikin/pen/BaxdOaR).

```js
const {  Row, Col  } = antd;

const App = () => (
  <Row>
    <Col className={'first'} span={16}>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/400?random=1"/>
    </Col>
    <Col span={8}>
      <Row>
         <Col className={'second'} span={24}>
           <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/400?random=2"/>
         </Col>
         <Col className={'third'} span={24}>
           <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/400?random=3"/>
         </Col>
      </Row>
    </Col>
  </Row>
)
const ComponentDemo = App;


ReactDOM.render(<ComponentDemo />, mountNode);
```

I'm getting data from the server. There may be more than 3 of them there. I should output the first 3 like this.  The rest will be displayed after pressing the button.  How can this effect be achieved in `myData.map()`. To output these elements without using indexes?

I will try do somthing like this

```
                dataSale.slice(0,maxCount).map(({...item},index)=>(
                    (index===0)?(
                        <Col key = {index}  span={16}>
                            <SaleCard {...item}/>
                        </Col>
                        ):(
                            <Col key={index} span={8}>
                                <SaleCard {...item}/>
                            </Col>
                    )

                ))
```

Comment: Rest of the elements will have the same layout as the first 3 elements? (first column with span 16 with one image and second column with span 8 will have two images)

Comment: @MuhammadNoumanRafique yes

Comment: When you click on button to display rest of the sales, it should display all the data or it should one row at a time? For example, you press button it show second row, you press the button again, it shows next row....

Comment: @MuhammadNoumanRafique display all data

Comment: Is the button on the code pen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this helps. The following code should work with any number of image links sent by the server. I have mocked with 9 images.
I followed components approach, like what you are supposed to when working with React. I created some components and pieced them back-together to create the design that you wanted to with `map()`.

```js
const {  Row, Col, Button } = antd;
const {useState} = React;

const data = [
  "https://picsum.photos/800/400?random=1",
  "https://picsum.photos/800/400?random=2",
  "https://picsum.photos/800/400?random=3",
  "https://picsum.photos/800/400?random=4",
  "https://picsum.photos/800/400?random=5",
  "https://picsum.photos/800/400?random=6",
  "https://picsum.photos/800/400?random=7",
  "https://picsum.photos/800/400?random=8",
  "https://picsum.photos/800/400?random=9",
]

const ColWithImage = (props) => (
  <Col span={props.n % 3 == 1 ? 16 : 24}>
    <img src={data[props.n-1]}/>
  </Col>
)

const MainRow = (props) => {
  const k = props.n*3 + 1;
  return (
    <Row>    
      <ColWithImage n={k}/>
    <Col span={8}>
      <Row>
         <ColWithImage n={k+1}/>
         <ColWithImage n={k+2}/>
      </Row>
    </Col>
  </Row>
)}

const Container = (props) => {
  // Create an iterable array depending upon the number of image links
  const arr = Array.from(Array(Math.floor(data.length/3)))
  // Show only one row if the button is not clicked
  // But show all the rows if the button is clicked
  return !props.buttonClicked 
    ? <><MainRow n={0}/></>
    : (<>
        {
          arr.map((item, index) =>  <MainRow key={index} n={index}/>)
        }
      </>)
}

const App = () => { 
  const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false);
  const [buttonText, setButtonText ] = useState("Show More");
  
  const handleClick = () => {
    setButtonClicked(!buttonClicked);
    setButtonText(buttonClicked ? "Show More" : "Show Less");  
  }
  
  return (<>
    <Container buttonClicked={buttonClicked}/>
    <Button onClick={handleClick}>{buttonText}</Button>
      </>)
}
const ComponentDemo = App;
ReactDOM.render(<ComponentDemo />, mountNode);
```

You can view the result [here](https://codepen.io/ghimire_saurav/pen/eYryYyg?editors=0011).

Answer (score 1):

I created a `SalesView` component and it will render the layout as per you requirement. It receives an items array of length less than or equal to 3 (Suppose you have total 5 records, only two records will be displayed in second row).

Hope this solution solves your problem.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Row, Col, Button } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.min.css";

const list = Array.from({ length: 20 }).map((_, i) => ({
  id: i,
  url: `https://picsum.photos/800/400?random=${i + 1}`,
}));

const SalesCard = ({ id, url }) => {
  return <img src={url} />;
};

const SalesView = ({ items }) => {
  return (
    <Row>
      {items?.[0] && (
        <Col span={16}>
          <SalesCard {...items[0]} />
        </Col>
      )}
      {items.length > 2 && (
        <Col span={8}>
          <Row>
            {items?.[1] && (
              <Col span={24}>
                <SalesCard {...items[1]} />
              </Col>
            )}
            {items?.[2] && (
              <Col span={24}>
                <SalesCard {...items[2]} />
              </Col>
            )}
          </Row>
        </Col>
      )}
    </Row>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [showAll, setShowAll] = useState(false);
  const totalChunks = Math.ceil(list.length / 3);

  const data = Array.from({ length: showAll ? totalChunks : 1 }).map((_, index) => {
    const startIndex = index * 3;
    const endIndex = startIndex + 3;

    return <SalesView key={index} items={list.slice(startIndex, endIndex)} />;
  });

  const onClick = () => setShowAll(true);

  return (
    <>
      {data}
      {!showAll && <Button onClick={onClick}>Show More</Button>}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it via CSS or use ternary

```
dataSale.map((item, index) => 
    <Col key={index} span={index < 3 ? 16 : 8}>
        <SaleCard {...item}/>
    </Col>
)
```

Comment: in this case, the 3 image will not be under 2 . it will go to the next line and will be under 1

Comment: do you have an example of what you trying to do?

Comment: yes. https://codepen.io/sharoikin/pen/BaxdOaR